# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ,PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, functional-programming

what i do to run these script ?

```
DECLARE
 DBlink varchar2(20);
 type array_t is varray(2) of varchar2(20);
   array array_t := array_t('T', 'RA') ;
   BEGIN
  FOR i in 1..array.count 
  LOOP
  DBlink := array_t(i) ;
      insert into Database_size_2 (DBNAME,date1,Dbsize)values(DBlink,sysdate,11 ) ;
    END LOOP ;
 END ;
```

ERROR at line 8:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 8, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your PL/SQL. You are using the actual type `array_t` rather than the variable `array` that you have defined in your DECLARE block:

```
DECLARE
   DBlink varchar2(20);
   type array_t is varray(2) of varchar2(20);
   array array_t := array_t('T', 'RA') ;
BEGIN
   FOR i in 1..array.count 
   LOOP
      DBlink := array(i) ;
      insert into Database_size_2 (DBNAME,date1,Dbsize) values (DBlink,sysdate,11 ) ;
   END LOOP ;
END;
```

You actually don't need the variable `DBLink` at all but can use the array entry directly:

```
DECLARE
   type array_t is varray(2) of varchar2(20);
   array array_t := array_t('T', 'RA') ;
BEGIN
   FOR i in 1..array.count 
   LOOP
      insert into Database_size_2 (DBNAME,date1,Dbsize) values (array(i),sysdate,11 ) ;
   END LOOP ;
END;
```